# Get Wednesday in a given week

Tags: google-sheets

Assuming I know the current week through =WEEKNUM(B1). B1 is a date in that week. I am now trying to get the date of Wednesday in that week. Anyone knows how to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [WEEKDAY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092985?hl=en) macro to get the day in the week as a number:

```
=WEEKDAY(DATE(1995,3,12)) -> 1
```

Now, you can get the date for wednesday as follows, assuming `B1` is the date:

```
=B1+(4-WEEKDAY(B1))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem is just that I don't know what date Wednesday is. I only know either Friday or Saturday of that week (it varies).

Answer (score 0):

When a cell contains the week number:

```
=(DATE(YEAR(NOW()),1,1)+~CELL NUMBER~*7) -MOD(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(NOW()),1,1)+~CELL NUMBER~*7)-4,7)
```

When the cell contains a date (not week number)

```
=~CELL REF~-MOD(WEEKDAY(~CELL REF~)-4,7)+7
```